# RSS feeds reappearing in my reader

Tags: support, rss

I'm reading this site with [The Old Reader](http://theoldreader.com/). Ancient posts (like [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/357/how-do-i-monitor-and-or-control-the-temperature-of-the-soc) and [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4890/keeping-system-time-without-network)) keep reappearing daily as unread. Is this a thing with SE's RSS feeds, or with the reader I'm using?

Comment: Is this just the case with RaspberryPi.SE or all the StackExchange sites?

Comment: I suspect this is because posts re-appear when updated?

Comment: Just Raspberry Pi.

It seems that the post reappears in the RSS feed if even one minor part is edited. Yuck; how annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be somewhat annoying, but... The "recent questions feed" link on the front page gives you a feed of *active* questions (same as what's displayed on the front page). So every time a question is modified (edited, answered, answer-edited, etc.) it'll reappear in the feed.

If you want to get a feed of new questions only, you can use https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/feeds/newest instead.